# Chamar View em outro Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotas

Tenho 2 Controller's **HomeController** e **UsuarioController** dentro de **UsuarioController** tenho um método que valida o usuário.
    Se for válido, quero que ele redirecione para a pagina *Index* do *HomeController* Porém quando tento redirecionar, cai na pagina:

http://localhost:62378/Usuario/Home/Index

Segue o método de redirecionamento para ilustrar melhor o cenário.

```
var usuarioValido = _usuario.Login(email, senha);
        if (usuarioValido == true)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("~/Home/Index");
        }
        return View("Usuario Não encontrado");
```

Como faço esse roteamento de maneira correta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O uso de `RedirectToAction` está errado. É assim:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

[Veja todos os usos possíveis aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).